# Algebraic Proof that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \binom{r}{k} \binom{m+n-r}{m-k} = \binom{m+n}{m}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How do I prove that:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \binom{r}{k} \binom{m+n-r}{m-k} = \binom{m+n}{m} ~~~~~~~~~ (r <= m + n) $$

by using an algebraic identity?

*My Attempt:*

I know of the generating functions: 
$$ (1 + x)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{r}{k} x^k ~~~~~  and ~~~~~~
 \frac {1}{(1 + x)^{n + 1}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n + k}{k} x^k $$

and after a bit of trial and error I came up with the algebraic identity:

$$(1 - x)^r  \frac {1}{(1 - x)^{n + r + 1}} = \frac {1}{(1 - x)^{n + 1}} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (a)$$

The right hand side of (a) clearly matches the 2nd generating function. So:

$$ \frac {1}{(1 + x)^{n + 1}} = \sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom{n + m}{m} x^m  $$

The left hand side of (a) can be expressed as product of summations:

$$\begin{align*}
\displaystyle{ 
(1 - x)^r  \frac {1}{(1 - x)^{n + r + 1}} } 

&=\displaystyle{
\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{m} (-x)^m \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n + r + k}{k} x^k
} \\
&=\displaystyle{
\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m} \binom{r}{k} (-x)^k \binom{n + r + m - k}{m - k} x^{m-k} 
} \\
&=\displaystyle{
\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m} \binom{r}{k} \binom{n + r + m - k}{m - k} (-1)^k x^m
}
\end{align*}$$

But now I am stuck since I don't know how to make:

$$ \binom{n + r + m - k}{m - k} (-1)^k ~~~~ equal ~~~~  \binom{m+n-r}{m-k} ~~~~~ ?????  $$

to complete the proof.

Will my method work or should I be using another algebraic identity? I am quite new to combinatorics so please keep concepts understandable by a beginner. Thanks :)

EDIT

*The answer*

It turns out that my equation wasn't taking me anywhere close to the answer - LOL! Here is the answer with the new algebraic identity:

$$\begin{align*}

(1 + x)^r  (1 + x)^{m+n-r} &= (1 + x)^{m + n} \\


\sum\limits_{m=0}^r \binom{r}{m} x^m 
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m + n-r} \binom{n+m-r}{k} x^k &=
\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n + m} \binom{n+m}{m} x^m
 \\

\sum\limits_{m=0}^{r + (m+n-r)} \sum\limits_{k=0}^m 
\binom{r}{m} \binom{n+m-r}{m-k} x^m &=
\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n + m} \binom{n+m}{m} x^m
 \\

\sum\limits_{m=0}^{m+n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^m 
\binom{r}{m} \binom{n+m-r}{m-k} x^m &=
\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n + m} \binom{n+m}{m} x^m
 \\


\end{align*}$$

Equating coefficients gives:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \binom{r}{m} \binom{n+m-r}{m-k}  =
\binom{n+m}{m} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ QED!!! $$

Comment: Your work looks good, and you do get a nice identity for binomial coefficients that way.  Unfortunately, it's not the one you want to prove, and I don't think it's very close to the one you want to prove.  If you follow Broskiana's suggestion, you'll see that the problem is a bit simpler than what you were attempting.  (One other comment-- when you list the two generating functions you know, the second one should be $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$, not $\frac{1}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$.  Obviously, you realize this, since all your work is correct!)

Comment: @jonas-kibelbek Thanks for reviewing though my work even though it was way off. I am new to combinatorics so it is good to know my manipulations are ok :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know binomial series i think you can compare the coefficient of $ x^m $ in $ (1+x)^r(1+x)^{m+n-r} $ and $ (1+x)^{n+m} $. It should be very straight forward from here.

Comment: LOL - It takes 3 lines using your method. Thanks! My method was "not very close" as mentioned by Jonas. Why didn't I think of that equation before? Sometimes my brain just seems to get stuck..... O_O

Comment: @Johann: By the way, the combinatorial proof and algebraic proof are related.  The combinatorial proof is this: We want to count the ways to choose $m$ marbles from a set of $m+n$ marbles (which is $\binom{m+n}{m}$).  Suppose $r$ of the marbles are red-- then when we choose $m$ marbles, we will get $k$ red ones, where $k$ could be any number from 0 to $r$, and $m-k$ ordinary marbles (that is, $\sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k} \binom{m+n-r}{m-k}$).  In the algebraic proof, pulling out the factor $(1+x)^r$ is kind of like painting those $r$ copies of $x$ red.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks a lot! I am sure I will to need to be able to understand and do combinatorial proofs somewhere in the course so your combinatorial approach is most appreciated...Cheers