# How to find the number of solutions for $x_1+2x_2+5x_3=10$?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a question taken from Discrete mathematics by Kenneth Rosen:

Find the number of ways to make change for \$100 using \$10, \$20 and \$50 bills.

My approach:

Let number of \$10 notes be $x_1$.
Let number of \$20 notes be $x_2$.
Let number of \$50 notes be $x_3$.

Then the number of ways is equal to

number of solutions of $10x_1+20x_2+50x_3=100$ and so $x_1+2x_2+5x_3=10$.

Now I don't know how to find the number of solutions to this equation.

Comment: What is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the Taylor series at the origin of $$\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^5}$$ ?

Comment: I will tell you even more: due to the triple pole at $x=1$, the number of ways for changing $n$ dollars approaches $\frac{(n+1)(n+7)}{20}$ for large values of $n$.

Comment: It should take about 1 minute to "brute force" through all of the solutions.

Comment: For a typesetting note, if you want a dollar sign to appear as an actual dollar sign, put a slash in front of it like `\$`, otherwise it will be used to initiate in-line mathmode.

Comment: Is it same as searching for coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^5)^{10}$? still no improvement.

Comment: As an additional note for writing questions and solutions, equals signs should **only** be used for equality, never for a "here's the next step."  You wrote $10x_1+\dots=100\color{red}{=}x_1+\dots=10$, which if the equals sign in the middle were interpreted as an equals sign would imply that you wrote $100=10$ which is flat out false (*in normal circumstances*).  Use words, or an arrow, or begin a new line in place of erroneous equals signs like that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio IMHO it is more understandable this $$( 0,\;  0,\;  2),\; ( 0,\;  5,\;  0),\; ( 1,\;     2,\;  1),\; ( 2,\;  4,\;  0),\; ( 3,\;  1,\;     1),\; ( 4,\;  3,\;  0),\; ( 5,\;  0,\;  1),\; (    6,\;  2,\;  0),\; ( 8,\;  1,\;  0),\; ( 10,\; 0,\;  0)$$

Comment: @Raffaele: I agree, but such representation does not provide any insight on the (quadratic) growth of the number of representations.

Comment: @samjoe no, it is not the same as finding the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^5)^{10}$.  That would have been if ten parts must be used, the order of the parts mattered and parts of size zero were allowed.  E.g. a \$50 followed by five \$10's followed by four \$0's would be considered a different outcome than three \$10's followed by a \$50 followed by four \$0's and then the rest of the \$10's.  That is clearly not what is intended.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for explanation! I am a little new to generating functions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **first variant**
>
> When looking for non-negative integral solutions $x_1,x_2,x_3$ we notice that the possible solutions of $x_3$ in
>   \begin{align*}
>   x_1+2x_2+5x_3=10\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
>
> are $x_3\in\{0,1,2\}$ since $0\leq 5x_3\leq 10$.
>
> Setting these three values for $x_3$ we consider instead of (1) the three equations
>   \begin{align*}
>   x_1+2x_2&=10\\
>   x_1+2x_2&=5\\
>   x_1+2x_2&=0\\
> \end{align*}
>
> The first equation has $6$ admissible values $x_2\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, the second equation has $3$ admissible values $x_2\in\{0,1,2\}$ and the third equation has one admissible value $x_2\in\{0\}$. The value of $x_1$ is then uniquely determined.
>
> The number of admissible solutions of (1) is
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{6+3+1=10}
> \end{align*}

**second variant**

We follow the comment from @JackDAurizio and use *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* to find the number of admissible solutions.

Values of $x_3$ represent zero or more multiples of $5$ which can be encoded as
\begin{align*}
  1+x^5+x^{10}+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x^5}
  \end{align*}

We argue similarly when considerung values of $x_1$ and $x_2$. Since the right hand side of (1) is $10$ we look for the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{1-x^5}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}
  \end{align*}

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series $A(x)$. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[x^n]A(x)=[x^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j=a_n
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{10}]}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-x^5}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}}\\
> &=[x^{10}](1+x^5+x^{10})\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{10}]+[x^5]+[x^0]\right)\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^{10}](1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}\\
> &\qquad +[x^5](1+x^2+x^4)\frac{1}{1-x}+[x^0]\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{4}\\
> &=6+3+1\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=10}
> \end{align*}
>   showing the number of solutions is $10$.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we expand $\frac{1}{1-x^5}$ up to $x^{10}$ since other terms do not contribute to $[x^{10}]$.
- In (3) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (4) we expand $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ similarly as we did in (2).
- In (5) we notice that we could work as we did in (3) and since $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$ each term has a contribution of $1$.

Comment: I understood your first solution.I can understand  the second solution that you have posted using generating functions upto the point where you have started using coefficient of operator $[x^n]$. I don't understand how this operator works. Please elaborate a little about this operator.

Comment: @KishanKumar: Explanation added. See also for instance *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475217/prove-a-formula-containing-binomial-coefficients/2475248#2475248)*.

Comment: KishanKumar: You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This is exactly the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: @algorhythm: You're welcome. :-)